# Socket.IO setting poll timeout

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm using Socket.IO on Node.js.
The Example here: http://socket.io/#how-to-use
First Example.

I have tested on my computer, it works great. ( Installed on VPS, connect by IP. not localhost )

But the problem is, my friends, they visit the page:
http://112.78.8.221:8085/

Press F12 for debug , under Console, they show not thing.

But in my browser console ( Chrome, Firefox ) , I see a object return.

On debug of my friend:
I see :

1. jsonppolling closed due to exceeded duration
2. setting request `GET /socket.io/1/jsonp-polling/blablabalblabal`
3. Setting poll timeout
4. discatding transport and same as xhr-polling, timeout and discard.

So, both of us used latest version of Chrome and FF, can u guys help on this one? a week with this problem already :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is something strange going on with his network. Maybe he is going through a proxy connection or something? I was able to hit your service and got an object back without a problem. Some offices and universities will also block ports other than the common 80, 443, 22, etc. If you can, try hosting on a lower port number, or if possible on port 80 to eliminate that as a cause of the problem.